# How to abandon/rollback the modifications done into a model entity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I changed some value of an entity from the db, but now I want to discard all the changes. How can I do this?

I tried following:

```
    u = User.find(1)
    u.nick = "dddd"

    u.abandon?  #i didn't want rollback the chage of the u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
u.reload
```

It'll reload the entity from the database.

Comment: the question is not even about reloading the data.  it is about how to abandon the change.  if you save it, then reloading won't work, so the real thing is about not saving it, not about reloading

Answer (score 1):

if you don't save it (by using `u.save`), then it is not made into the persistent storage.  You can just do `u = User.find(1)` again to reload the value from the db.